# How to write join query in dynamic ax 2012 using native query option?

Tags: sql, microsoft-dynamics

I am able to write simple query as below in native query

```
> <ns3:Object xmlns:ns2="XXXX">
>     <CompanyRanges xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="XXXXX"/>
>     <DataSources>
>         <QueryDataSourceMetadata>
>             <Company xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="XXXX"/>
>             <DataSources xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="SSSSS"/>
>             <Enabled>true</Enabled>
>             <Fields>
>                 <QueryFieldMetadata xsi:type="QueryDataFieldMetadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>                     <FieldName>ItemId</FieldName>
>                     <SelectionField>Database</SelectionField>
>                     <TableName xsi:nil="true"/>
>                 </QueryFieldMetadata>
>             </Fields>
>             <LabelId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>             <Name>InventTable</Name>
>             
>             <Relations xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>             <Table>InventTable</Table>
>         </QueryDataSourceMetadata>
>     </DataSources>
>     <Description xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>     <Filters xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>     <GroupByFields xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>     <HavingFilters xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>     <Name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>     </ns3:Object>
```

But I want to join multiple tables in dynamic ax using native query.
Can anyone please help!

Thanks in advance.